# Apache Camel Route Management

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I have a simple route in my camel springboot app, it  picks up a file, rename it, and then sends a kafka message, it's working fine, but I notice if there is an issue in kafka connection when application starts up, for example, failed authentication due to: Authentication failed: Invalid username or password, the route will be started, camel health check return "up",  here is my route:

{

```
    onException(Exception.class)
            .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "TransferRoute failed.")
            .maximumRedeliveries(maximumRedeliveries).redeliveryDelay(redeliveryDelay)
            .handled(true);

    from(
            "file:{{camel.route.from}}?readLock=changed")
            .routeId("{{camel.route.route-id}}")
            .log("${routeId} ${camelId}")
            .to("file:{{camel.route.to}}?fileName={{camel.route.file-name.prefix}}.${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}.txt")
            .log("file is renamed and routed to destination directory.")
            .process(fileNotificationProcessor)
            .log("${routeId} ${camelId} ${body}")
            .to("kafka:{{kafka.notification.topic}}?retries={{kafka.notification.retries}}")
            .log("Kafka Notification message is sent successfully.");
}
```

1. I don't want the route to be started, if there is an issue to connect to Kafka. I am actually working on the error handling part:
2. when the file is renamed and moved to another directory, if there is any issue to send the kafka message, i would like to roll back the file movement, is that possible?

thanks a lot!